# How to add placeholder text into $email

Tags: php, forms, email, registration

I have a page called **check.php** which contains all the validation for a registration form but i would like to basically add the placeholder (I use ) text called **`@example.com`** into the database

**Following is what I currently have**
`$email = $_POST['email'];`

**Below is what I wanted to do**
`$email = $_POST['email@example.com'];`

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate strings? Be more specific - give us 5 difference inputs and 5 of their correct outputs, and write what *you* have tried so far.

Comment: Can you clarify? From your code it looks like you want the form field that collects the email to be called `email@example.com` ... but I don't think that's what you're saying. Where do you want `@example.com` to end up? You said the database, but can you clarify?

Comment: i like have something like google [link](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-en) where registering for an email account does not need to fill in the @example.com just your preferred username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$email = $_POST['email'].'@example.com'`;

Comment: @JialeLeong Please do note that if `$_POST['email']` is `me@domain.com` this would turn into `me@domain.com@example.com`.

Comment: oh is it, can you please help me to the more corrected coding

Comment: @JialeLeong Use `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` and if it doesn't validate then add your domain. I'm sure you can figure it out if you simply try.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you can be:

```
$email = 'email@example.com';
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
   $email = $_POST['email']; 
}
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="<?= $email ?>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Of course you change you script to this! You way is not right solution